# Inject header in HAProxy redirect function

Tags: http, haproxy, http-headers

I have HAProxy 1.5.8.

I have this basic 301 rule :

```
frontend http_frontend
  bind *:80
  mode http
  redirect location https://xxxx.com code 301
```

The response looks like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-length: 0
Location: https://xxxx.com
Connection: close
```

I need to add a date in the header, like a regular webserver would do.

**respadd** function doesn't seems to affect the redirect.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here, a 301 just tells a client to go somewhere else and most browsers will cache that information so that they don't have to keep looking it up.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this, Willy from HaProxy identified the solution here:

https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg25061.html

```
http-request redirect location "https://blah..\r\nDate: xyz"
```

The problem I was wanting to solve was to add a HSTS header, but I guess you could use it for a date.

It isn't pretty, but does work, and I have just implemented it, for us we also wanted to render a header identifying the box that was generating the redirect, as we have multiple HaProxy boxes.

This was tested by me in HaProxy 1.6, I can't vouch for other versions.

Comment: does that still work with HaProxy 2.0 with htx?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for any browser that has ever seen the redirect. It is cached indefinitely. A 301 redirect should only be used when you are retiring a site permanently, and even then it's a bad idea - you loose visibility of the traffic still hitting the old site.

So change it to a 302 redirect before you do anything else.

Haproxy is not a webserver. It has no means to generate a header contains dynamic data - if you really want a date header, use a webserver. There are several lightweight ones capable of this task.

Alternatively tell us why you *need* such a header and we might be able to advise on a more apposite solution.

Comment: It's important for SEO, but you never know  when the url could be used again.
I don't need dynamic header value. 
```
Cache-Context: max-age=3600
```
would be great.

Comment: I keep being told that 301s are important for SEO. But the SEs don't publish information detailled enough to support that assertion. And while this keeps getting repeated in SEO circles I've not been able to find anything beyond opinions - no meaurements.

Comment: From a technical point of view canonical URLs are a much more appropriate way to address the underlying issue and hence should be more effective than any type of explicit redirection. Give the the search engines are not telling us what value they place on a 301 over the other redirects, it seems VERY unlikely that they would tell us how they interpret a caching value for what is DEFINED IN THE SPECIFICATION AS PERMANENT. If you have evidence to the contrary, I for one would really like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I found in github issue discussion it is possilbe since Haproxy 2.2

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72830822/1849577

```
http-after-response set-header Cache-Control max-age=3600 if {condition}
```